# Visual Studio popup: “the operation could not be completed”

Tags: visual-studio

When I tried to load my project(out of my workspace) ,I was getting the error "Operation could not Completed".

Answer (score 0):

After observation I found that I was in another branch(in my workspace).
I switched to the appropriate git branch where I developed my code.The problem resolved.